# add value from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the col_final_X and col_final_Y I only need the Val of ID **140** and **141**. But the point is that the ID and the values of each row appears on different columns. As you can see below the first row with **ID** 1 and name **James** the **140** appears on **col_2_ID** and the Value of it on **col_2_VAL** and the 141 on **col_3_ID** and the Value of it on **col_3_VALUE** and the third row appears the id **141** on col_1_ID and the value on col_1_VAL and so on.

So the quastion is how can I add the value of ID **140** into **col_final_X** and the value of ID **141** intot **col_final_Y** of each row?. Iam using panda dataframework. Any suggestions would be helpful and I hope I made it clear enough. Thanks in advance

csv file

```
| ID| Name |col_1_ID|col_1_VAL|col_2_ID|col_2_VAL|col_3_ID|col_3_VAL|col_final_X|col_final_Y|
| 1 | James|  56    |Back     |140     |56.8     |141     |44.9     |           |           |
| 2 | John |  140   |40       |NaN     |NaN      |140     |90.1     |           |           |
| 3 | Mike |  141   |77.4     |140     |40       |NaN     |NaN      |           |           |
```

Answer (score 1):

First solution with map between `_ID` and `_VAL` DataFrames:

```
#check all columns endswith _ID
df1 = df.filter(regex='_ID$')
df2 = df.filter(regex='_VAL$')

#for new columns dynamic set names and test values in dictionary
mapping = {140: 'col_final_X', 141: 'col_final_Y'}

for k, v in mapping.items():

    #test number
    df11 = df1.eq(k)
    df11.columns = df11.columns.str.replace(r'_ID$', r'_VAL', regex=True)
    df[v] = df2.where(df11).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]


print (df)
   ID   Name  col_1_ID col_1_VAL  col_2_ID  col_2_VAL  col_3_ID  col_3_VAL  \
0   1  James        56      Back     140.0       56.8     141.0       44.9   
1   2   John       140        40       NaN        NaN     140.0       90.1   
2   3   Mike       141      77.4     140.0       40.0       NaN        NaN   

  col_final_X col_final_Y  
0        56.8        44.9  
1          40         NaN  
2        40.0        77.4
```

Second solution with [`indexing-lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup):

```
#check all columns endswith _ID
df1 = df.filter(regex='_ID$')

#for new columns dynamic set names and test values in dictionary
mapping = {140: 'col_final_X', 141: 'col_final_Y'}

for k, v in mapping.items():

    #test number
    m = df1.eq(k)
    #get first matched value
    s = m.idxmax(axis=1).str.replace(r'_ID$', r'_VAL', regex=True)
    
    #found original columns ends with _VAL by lookup
    idx, cols = pd.factorize(s)
    #if not exist 140 or 141 per ro set NaN
    df[v] = (pd.Series(df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx], 
                       index=df.index)
               .where(m.any(axis=1)))

print (df)

   ID   Name  col_1_ID col_1_VAL  col_2_ID  col_2_VAL  col_3_ID  col_3_VAL  \
0   1  James        56      Back     140.0       56.8     141.0       44.9   
1   2   John       140        40       NaN        NaN     140.0       90.1   
2   3   Mike       141      77.4     140.0       40.0       NaN        NaN   

  col_final_X col_final_Y  
0        56.8        44.9  
1          40         NaN  
2        40.0        77.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using reshaping of your DataFrame with a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
cols = ['col_final_X', 'col_final_Y']
values = [140, 141]

df[cols] = (
 df # rework column names
   .set_index(['ID', 'Name'])
   .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True), axis=1))
   .rename(columns={'ID': 'col'}).stack(0).reset_index()
   # reshape getting the first desired value
   .pivot_table(index='ID', columns='col', values='VAL', aggfunc='first')
   # reindex
   .reindex(index=df.index, columns=values).to_numpy()
)
```

Output:

```
   ID   Name  col_1_ID col_1_VAL  col_2_ID  col_2_VAL  col_3_ID  col_3_VAL  \
0   1  James        56      Back     140.0       56.8     141.0       44.9   
1   2   John       140        40       NaN        NaN     140.0       90.1   
2   3   Mike       141      77.4     140.0       40.0       NaN        NaN   

  col_final_X col_final_Y  
0         NaN         NaN  
1        56.8        44.9  
2          40         NaN
```